# Error Parse JSON with org.json

Tags: java, json

I have a json like below. I want to get value from attribute title. I use library org.json.

```
{
  "media": {
    "id": 470,
    "user_id": 1,
    "category_id": 1,
    "title": "obama",
    "vid_src": null
  },
  "view_increment": false
}
```

This is my code to get title value from myjson but it not works. Whats wrong with my code?

```
String myJson = "{\"media\":{\"id\":470,\"user_id\":1,\"category_id\":1,\"title\":\"obama\",\"vid_src\":null},\"view_increment\":false}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myJson);
String title = obj.getJSONObject("media").getString("title");
System.out.println("Title = "+title);
```

Comment: What's the issue?are you getting any error?

Comment: org.json has bugs/non compliance in parsing the json. Use Gson from google instead. I tested both and GSON is compliant (no problems found so far, parsing >250000 json strings a day with it).

Comment: Please show us the full code. I'll bet the error occurs where you define `myjson`.

Comment: I've executed the code and there is no problem displaying the value.

Comment: What version of org.json you are using

Comment: Are you putting in a try catch block.Because You have to

Comment: @Madhan : json-2014113.jar

Comment: I've tried that too.No error till now

Comment: @ZulkifliSaid Don't use a `.jar` file. Take the source and place it in a package `org.json`.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi there is no point in doing that

Comment: @ZulkifliSaid post your full code from the class right from the import to main function